# How to execute different SQL statements at once

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, batch-processing

I know that "Batch Processing allows us to group related SQL statements into a batch and submit them with one call to the database". But my question is how to execute different SQL statements at once i.e I want to insert records to Employee table, Address table , Department table with one call to database. So, is it possible? I'm using PostgreSQL and java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't insert into multiple tables in one statement, but you can do it *effectively* "at once" by using a transaction:

```
begin;
insert into table1 ...;
insert into table2 ...;
insert into table3 ...;
commit;
```

All statements within the transaction (between `begin` and `commit`) are treated atomically - ie as if they are "one statement".

Answer (score 1):

Group those statements into an anonymous code block and execute that.

See
http://nixmash.com/postgresql/using-postgresql-anonymous-code-blocks/